# What type of fiber optical cable do I need to use for the VNX5200?

Tags: optical-media

I have the EMC VNX5200 and two Brocade 300 SAN switches sitting in my office. I now need to order optical cables to connect these devices. Somebody told me that they are not the standard fiber cables that we normally would order and I need to verify the part numbers and fiber type and quality and we need to make sure they are the right quality and type. Is that true? I thought the regular OM1 or OM2 MMF should work. If that's not right, what "type and quality" I need to look for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well the VNX is very flexible so offers both Ethernet and FC ports but given you have FC-only switches I'm going to assume that you have FC ports in your VNX - you NEED to check this though as they kind of look the same. Either way if you want to do 8Gbps FC between the devices and they're not too far from each other (under 100m) then go for OM3 LC-to-LC fibres - obviously you'll need the right optics in your switches too. If they're going directly from VNC to the switches then you can get 50um or 62.5um inner core fibres as it won't matter but if you're going via patching of any type you need to match that.

Comment: The VNX will be in the same rack as the Brocade. So I don't worry about the cable length. I think the OM3 LC-LC should be fine with the VNX. The only one I need to think of is Brocade. The product description says "320,8P,FULL FABRIC,8GB SWL SFPS,BR". Do you think it will help to find out what cable needs for the Brocade? Thanks much!